# How to get name of Display Manager on Linux?

Tags: bash, gnome, kde, python, gui

I want to see `Display Manager` name (Gnome, KDE etc.) via python or bash script. Is there any command for it as `uname`? (I try fedora and Debian)

Comment: "GUI" is a bit vague. Are you interested in your desktop environment, your window manager or your display manager? For finding out the session manager on Debian, for example, you can use `readlink /etc/alternatives/x-session-manager` but this is definitely not portable (doesn't work on Fedora).

Comment: You can try [`xwininfo -id $(xprop -root | awk '/_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW\(WINDOW\)/{print $NF}')`][1] for the current window.


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/a/20534/10371

Comment: How do you plan to select the application if you don't know it's name? Is it a GUI that Python or Bash would've started up initially? `xwininfo` can give you information about the various GUI's running.

Comment: I want to install a package according to the type of GUI via script. My script must know the GUI name. Thus I asked the question.

Comment: I wrote wrong. My question is relevant with Display Manager or Desktop Manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may probably check the environment variable named `DESKTOP_SESSION`.

Comment: This seems to work well enough. Interestingly, though, I tried it in a root terminal (after `su`) and it was unset.

Comment: It reports `default` on my system. Not very helpful.

Comment: @JosephR. that is probably because the `root` user has not started any Desktop Session, it is your user who has launched it.

Comment: You're right. I was substituting my user's environment with `root`'s (via `su -`)

Comment: @Marco it should contain the desktop name choosen by the user at login time. If the content is `default`, then I think, it gets the first one in `/usr/share/xsessions`.

Answer (score 0):

As @eppesuig has said, the environment variable `DESKTOP_SESSION` may tell you the currently running session.

But that doesn't mean it is the only – or even normal – Desktop environment in use on that system. I usually use GNOME3, but sometimes I boot into KDE or Enlightenment.

If the point of this is to select a desktop-specific GUI package for installation, this really should be used to suggest a default option rather than making a firm decision. If I happened to be running KDE when I installed your app, I would be disappointed to discover I had only installed a QT interface if a GTK interface was available.